# How to fix error 1004 in sum range of cell?

Tags: excel

I have problem with this code:`

```
Worksheets("IO").Cells(i + 13, 2).Formula = _
        "=sum(" & Worksheets("IO").Range(Cells(i + 1, 6), Cells(i + 1, 5 + numjob)).Address & ")"
```

and other line code that use with sum of range of cell. Sometimes the code is working, but most of the time is not. What i need to fix? I get error 1004 of applications defined or object defined.

Comment: What error do you get?  we need more info then it only works sometimes.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what the formula your code should write is. (i.e. the desired result)

Comment: I get a error 1004 massage :application defined or object defined. I want to define a formula cell by sum of range of cell. The error is probably because problem in the range...

Comment: You need to qualify the `Cells` calls inside the `Range` with the worksheet.

Comment: How to qualify the cell?  why sometime its work and sometimes its not?

Comment: And if you mean to write: cells(i, j). Address, its not work